# Имитация нажатия enter в поле input с заполнением

Tags: javascript

здравствуйте, есть сайт с таким поллевом вода сообщений в чат.

```html
<form id="chatForm"><input class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..." id="chatMessage" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" type="text"></form>
```

Мне нужно что бы при входе на сайт отправлялось сообщение от меня в чат. Без перезагрузки страницы. Т.к. при отправки сообщения потом ещё нужно нажать кнопочку ок. В качестве подтверждения отправки. Т.е. отправка формы по средством sumbit. Не идёт. Потому что после самбит страница сразу перезагружается.

А если писать вручную сообщение и нажать enter сообщение отправляется и страница не перезагружается. Сразу скажу сайт не мой. Хочу сделать расширение.

Так я заполняю поле для отправки

```js
document.getElementById('chatMessage').value = 'Сообщение';
```

И нужно автоматизировать отправку.

Как можно реализовать отправку сообщения для этого поля имитацией нажатия кнопки enter?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  var form = document.querySelector('#chatForm');
  form.onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var message = document.querySelector('#chatMessage').value;
  }

</script>
```

В переменной message - ваш текст сообщения, дальше с помощью аякс отправляете его

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.YOUR_FORM.submit();
</script>
```

Т.е. ищешь любым удобным тебе способом свою форму (по классу, id и т.д.)), и вызываешь у нее метод submit();

Например так:

```
<form id="chatForm" action="YOUR_URL" name="YOUR_FORM">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..." id="chatMessage" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" type="text"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.YOUR_FORM.submit();
</script>
```

Т.е. тебе необходимо следующее:

1) Имеем форму.

2) Вводим данные.

3) Нажимаем enter.

4) Данные уходят. Страница не перезагружается.

5) Плюшки в довесок (например очистка всей или части формы).

Код не напишу, т.к. JavaScript не мое, но скажу как сделать и куда смотреть:

1) Делаешь форму.

2) Вводишь данные.

3) Нажимаешь enter.

3.1) На js перехватываешь стандартное поведение submit, отменяешь его.

3.2) Берешь данные и отправляешь используя ajax, может еще появились способы, но проще разобраться будет тебе с ajax.

4) Данные уходят.

4.1) С ajax ты можешь получить ответ (мол, данные приняты, все хорошо/плохо и отреагировать, обновить данные и т.д.)

5) Можешь очистить форму или сделать еще что нибудь полезное.

Comment: Нет, как раз таки submit() перезагружает страницу, я забыл указать в впоросе что мне нужно отправка сообщения в чат без перезагрузки страницы, просто будто я нажал кнопку enter.

Comment: Если ты имеешь форму и нажимаешь кнопку Enter, то страница перезагружается и это ожидаемая реакция.

Comment: нет, сайт не мой, и при нажатии на enter страница не перезагружается, мне просто нужно сделать имитацию нажатия кнопки enter в данном поле? как бы без отправки формы что ли

Comment: Тебе лучше более подробно переписать вопрос. То, что отправлять данные это понятно. Но, тебе, вероятнее всего делать это надо через определенный временной интервал, верно? Или реагируя на какие либо другие события. Сайт не твой, т.е. у тебя нет доступа к исходникам, верно? Поправив свой вопрос более корректно и дав больше информации будет проще ответить, а сейчас пальцем в небо тыкать... При всем желании помочь.

Comment: Написал более подробно. Прочтите. Надеюсь и более понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Если перезагрузка не нужна,то аякс вам в помощь!

Comment: А конкретно пример привести не сможете? сам не очень силен в этом, но интересно все таки